# Passing a string to an argument of filter (dplyr)

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

let's say I have a list of conditions:

```
input_list <- list(Species = "setosa",
                   Petal.Width = 0.2)
```

I can turn this list into a string:

```
x <- map(input_list, ~ paste0( " == ", "'", .[[1]], "'"))
conditions <- paste(names(x), x, collapse = ", ")


conditions
> [1] "Species  == 'setosa', Petal.Width  == '0.2'"
```

I would like to pass this string as conditions to filter :

```
iris %>% filter(rlang::sym(conditions))
```

But unfortunately I get an error

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
>     Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

Comment: `dplyr::right_join(iris, as.data.frame(input_list))`?

Comment: What's the context for this? Are you planning on taking the entire string that's saved as `conditions` as an argument to a function?

Comment: It's as part of a shiny app. The users' choices are collated into a list (`input_list`) and a data frame is returned with the filter conditions applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try collapsing your conditions into a string of form `cond1 & cond2` and use `eval(parse(text=...))`

```
input_list <- list(Species = "setosa",
                   Petal.Width = 0.2)

x <- map(input_list, ~ paste0( " == ", "'", .[[1]], "'"))
conditions <- paste(names(x), x, collapse = " & ")
conditions
# [1] "Species  == 'setosa' & Petal.Width  == '0.2'"

iris %>% filter(eval(parse(text = conditions)))
   # Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 7           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 8           5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 9           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
# etc
```

But I prefer Frank's answer in comment

Comment: is this answer the NSE way to do it?

Comment: No - I wouldn't consider this an NSE way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

`filter_` would do the job instead of `filter`

```
conds <- stringr::str_split(conditions, ", ")
iris %>% filter_(conds[[1]][1], conds[[1]][2])
```

**Update following up your comment:**

You can loop through the conditions which would work regardless of length:

```
for(i in conds[[1]]) {
  iris <- iris %>% filter_(i)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this will not work -  I am using my code as part of a function so the list length is not fixed

Comment: The `_` functions have been [deprecated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) in favor of NSE

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe; then you can loop through conditions, I updated the answer accordingly. @camille; I understand your point but it may be of help if it gets the job done for now. I will definitely keep it in mind as a good practice in the future. Thank you for pointing out!